# How would I express this MySQL JOINs query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables:

```
sh_feeds
    => id
    => feed_id

sh_subscriptions
    => id
    => user_id
    => feed_id
```

The query I'm trying to produce is:

> Select all from `sh_feeds` where `feed_id` matches a `feed_id` in
>   `sh_subscriptions` which corresponds to a `user_id` that matches
>   `$user_id`.

Slightly confusing, but hopefully that's clear enough.

I know there's going to be a lot of joining, and I've refreshed my memory with [this explainer](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/), but I still can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fairly easy, like this:

The inner join ensures that only rows are included for which the feed_id also occurs in sh_subscriptions.

```
SELECT f.* FROM sh_feeds f
INNER JOIN sh_subscriptions s ON f.feed_id = s.feed_id
WHERE s.user_id = $user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this works, though note the type at the end of line 2 - should be `s.feed_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM sh_feeds F
INNER JOIN sh_subscriptions S ON F.feed_id = S.feed_id
WHERE S.user_id = $user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sh.id ,sh.feed_id
FROM sh_feeds sh
INNER JOIN sh_subscriptions ss ON ss.feed_id = sh.feed_id
WHERE sh.user_id = '$user_id'
```